# Use Perl and Regex on Excel Cells to Combine Any Leading Numbers w/o Whitespaces

Tags: regex, excel, perl

Using Perl and Regex for an Excel cell, I am trying to combine the first leading numbers with whitespaces and leaving the other whitespaces alone in the same cell.  See the examples for the designated input and output.  My code is not giving me the designated output.

In Excel, the cell is as follows:

```
___________________________
     A
___________________________
Apples 2 Green 3 Red
____________________________
Grapefruits 3 Pink 2 Yellow
 ___________________________
Peaches
___________________________
Grapes
___________________________
```

The designated output is as follows:

```
___________________________
     A
___________________________
Apples 2Green 3 Red
____________________________
Grapefruits 3Pink 2 Yellow
___________________________
Peaches
___________________________
Grapes
___________________________
```

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook_R = $parser->parse('C:\Perl\Scripts\Muliple_Fruits.xls');

my $workbook_W = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('C:\Perl\Scripts\New_Multiple_Fruits.xls');
my $worksheet_W = $workbook_W->add_worksheet();

for my $worksheet_R ( $workbook_R->worksheets() ){

my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_R->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_R->col_range(); 

  for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
  for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

  my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );

  #if the cell contains a leading number with a space then combine it

  if ($cell->value =~ s/^(\S+\s+\d+)\s+/$1/) {
  $worksheet_W->write($row, $col,$cell->value())
  }

 #print the existing cell contents
 else {
 $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $cell->value);
      } 
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You've told us what you're trying to do, but you haven't told us what's actually happening! "It's not working" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Hint: _Binary `"=~"` binds a **scalar expression** to a pattern match._ https://perldoc.pl/perlop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$cell->value` is a *method call*, not a modifiable scalar, so you can't use `s///` on it

There's also no point in checking whether your substitution had any effect: you just want to write the value to the output whether it changed or not

Refactor your loop like this

```
for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

    for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

        my $value = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col )->value;

        $value =~ s/^(\S+\s+\d+)\s+/$1/;

        $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Borodin.  I've been working this all day.